# How do I set-up a search box in IE 9 like the one that was available in IE 8?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

In the top left-hand side in IE 8 there was a convenient search box which I loaded with DuckDuckGo.  I liked to be able to use this engine so easily but I just upgraded to IE 9 and there is no search box...how do I search my preferred engine directly from IE 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 doesn't have a separate search box, instead it lets you search directly from the address bar. It works pretty much the same as the search box in previous versions: press **Ctrl+E**, type your query and press **Enter**.

For more information, see here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Search-with-the-Internet-Explorer-9-Address-bar

If DuckDuckGo isn't currently your default search provider, you can select it at the bottom of the search result list that appears when you press **Ctrl+E**. If it isn't even listed there (though it should be, if you used it in IE8), go to http://duckduckgo.com/ and add it using the "IE" link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question/answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/ie9-no-option-to-have-different-search-engines/0aeca1d6-4d29-40f8-ad31-601351fc44d3) on Microsoft's Answers site.

You want to click the dropdown arrow next to the address bar:

[image: the arrow in IE9 address bar to add search engines]

Answer (score -3):

Search for Quero Toolbar. Install the Quero Toolbar. It adds a search box to the right of the Menu toolbar in IE 9, 10, 11. Please print out and read about all the options.

Sorry can't post an picture of IE and Quero Toolbar